# Kubernetes - NodePort service can be accessed only on node where pod is deployed

Tags: docker, kubernetes, iptables

I have set up a kubernetes cluster based on three VMs Centos 8 and I deployed a pod with nginx.

**IP addresses of the VMs:**

```
kubemaster 192.168.56.20
kubenode1 192.168.56.21
kubenode2 192.168.56.22
```

On each VM the interfaces and routes are defined as following:

```
ip addr:
lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:d2:1b:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s3
       valid_lft 75806sec preferred_lft 75806sec
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:df:77:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.22/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global noprefixroute enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:ff:47:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:ff:47:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:19:52:19:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: flannel.1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether 22:b8:b4:5a:5a:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.244.2.0/32 brd 10.244.2.0 scope global flannel.1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

ip route:
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp metric 100
default via 192.168.56.1 dev enp0s8 proto static metric 101
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 100
10.244.0.0/24 via 10.244.0.0 dev flannel.1 onlink
10.244.1.0/24 via 10.244.1.0 dev flannel.1 onlink
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
192.168.56.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.56.22 metric 101
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

On each VM I have two network adapters, one NAT for internet access (enp0s3) and one Host only Network for the 3 VMs to communicate (enp0s8) with each other (it is ok I tested it with ping command).

On each VM I applied the following firewall rules:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=6443/tcp # Kubernetes API server
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=2379-2380/tcp # etcd server client API
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=10250/tcp # Kubelet API
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=10251/tcp # kube-scheduler
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=10252/tcp # kube-controller-manager
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8285/udp # Flannel
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8472/udp # Flannel
firewall-cmd --add-masquerade –permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

finally I deployed the cluster and nginx with the following commands:

```
sudo kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.56.20 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 (for Flannel CNI)
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx
kubectl create service nodeport nginx --tcp=80:80
```

More general information of my cluster:

**kubectl get nodes -o wide**

```
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                KERNEL-VERSION                 CONTAINER-RUNTIME
kubemaster   Ready    master   3h8m   v1.19.2   192.168.56.20   <none>        CentOS Linux 8 (Core)   4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2.x86_64   docker://19.3.13
kubenode1    Ready    <none>   3h6m   v1.19.2   192.168.56.21   <none>        CentOS Linux 8 (Core)   4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2.x86_64   docker://19.3.13
kubenode2    Ready    <none>   165m   v1.19.2   192.168.56.22   <none>        CentOS Linux 8 (Core)   4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2.x86_64   docker://19.3.13
```

**kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide**

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP              NODE         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default       nginx-6799fc88d8-mrvsg               1/1     Running   0          3h     10.244.1.3      kubenode1    <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-f9fd979d6-6qxk9              1/1     Running   0          3h9m   10.244.1.2      kubenode1    <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-f9fd979d6-bj2fd              1/1     Running   0          3h9m   10.244.0.2      kubemaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   etcd-kubemaster                      1/1     Running   0          3h9m   192.168.56.20   kubemaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kubemaster            1/1     Running   0          3h9m   192.168.56.20   kubemaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kubemaster   1/1     Running   0          3h9m   192.168.56.20   kubemaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-fdv4p                1/1     Running   0          166m   192.168.56.22   kubenode2    <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-vvhsz                1/1     Running   0          3h6m   192.168.56.21   kubenode1    <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-vznl5                1/1     Running   0          3h6m   192.168.56.20   kubemaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-45tmz                     1/1     Running   0          3h9m   192.168.56.20   kubemaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-nb7jt                     1/1     Running   0          3h7m   192.168.56.21   kubenode1    <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-tl9n5                     1/1     Running   0          166m   192.168.56.22   kubenode2    <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kubemaster            1/1     Running   0          3h9m   192.168.56.20   kubemaster   <none>           <none>
```

**kubectl get service -o wide**

```
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        3h10m   <none>
nginx        NodePort    10.102.152.25   <none>        80:30086/TCP   179m    app=nginx
```

**Kubernetes version:**

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.2", GitCommit:"f5743093fd1c663cb0cbc89748f730662345d44d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-09-16T13:41:02Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.2", GitCommit:"f5743093fd1c663cb0cbc89748f730662345d44d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-09-16T13:32:58Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**iptables version:**

```
iptables v1.8.4 (nf_tables)
```

**Results and issue:**

- If I do curl 192.168.56.21:30086 from any VM -> OK I get the nginx code.
- If I try other IPs (e.g., curl 192.168.56.22:30086), it fails... (curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.56.22 port 30086: Connection time out)

**What I tried to debug:**

```
sudo netstat -antup | grep kube-proxy
o   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30086           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4116/kube-proxy
o   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10249         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4116/kube-proxy
o   tcp        0      0 192.168.56.20:49812     192.168.56.20:6443      ESTABLISHED 4116/kube-proxy
o   tcp6       0      0 :::10256                :::*                    LISTEN      4116/kube-proxy
```

Thus on each VM it seems the kube-proxy listens on port 30086 which is OK.

I tried to apply this rule on each node (found on another ticket) without any success:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
```

Do you have any idea why I can't reach the service from master node and node 2?

**First update:**

- It seems Centos 8 is not compatible with kubeadm. I changed for Centos 7 but still have the issue;
- The flannel pods created are using the wrong interface (enp0s3) instead of enp0s8. I modified the kube-flannel.yaml file and added the argument (--iface=enp0s8). Now my pods are using the correct interface.

```
kubectl logs kube-flannel-ds-nn6v4 -n kube-system:
I0929 06:19:36.842149       1 main.go:531] Using interface with name enp0s8 and address 192.168.56.22
I0929 06:19:36.842243       1 main.go:548] Defaulting external address to interface address (192.168.56.22)
```

Even by fixing these two things I still have the same issue...

**Second update:**

The final solution was to flush iptables on each VM with the following commands:

```
systemctl stop kubelet
systemctl stop docker
iptables --flush
iptables -tnat --flush
systemctl start kubelet
systemctl start docker
```

Now it is working correctly :)

Comment: My colleague had similar issue. Finally when I fixed this for him it turned out a bit unexpected. He have installed Docker via `curl https://get.docker.com | bash` instead of recommended way https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#docker. Installing Docker properly did the trick but I had no more time to figure out what was the real cause (version or whatever). Try it out and tell us if this is it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip but unfortunately it did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution after having switched to Centos 7 and correct Flannel configuration (see other comments).
Actually, I noticed some issues in the pods where coredns is running. Here is an example of what happens inside one of these pods:

```
kubectl logs coredns-f9fd979d6-8gtlp -n kube-system:
E0929 07:09:40.200413       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
```

The final solution was to flush iptables on each VM with the following commands:

```
systemctl stop kubelet
systemctl stop docker
iptables --flush
iptables -tnat --flush
systemctl start kubelet
systemctl start docker
```

Then I can access the service deployed from each VM :)

I am still not sure to understand clearly what was the issue. Here is some information:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/193
- https://www.developertyrone.com/blog/kubernetes-administrator-notes-coredns-fix-on-centos-no-route-to-host-networking-issues/

I will keep investigating and post more information here.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are running k8s on CentOS 8.

According to  [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#before-you-begin)  documentation the list of supported host operating systems is as follows:

> - Ubuntu 16.04+
> - Debian 9+
> - CentOS 7
> - Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7
> - Fedora 25+
> - HypriotOS v1.0.1+
> - Flatcar Container Linux (tested with 2512.3.0)

This  [article](https://medium.com/@liau.weijie/how-to-install-docker-and-kubernetes-cluster-on-redhat-8-centos-8-f774fc071e82)  mentioned that there are network issues on RHEL 8:

> **(2020/02/11 Update**: After installation, I keep facing pod network issue which is like deployed pod is unable to reach external network or pods deployed in different workers are unable to ping each other even I can see all nodes (master, worker1 and worker2) are ready via  *kubectl get nodes*. After checking through the Kubernetes.io official website, I observed the nfstables backend is not compatible with the current kubeadm packages. Please refer the following link in “**Ensure iptables tooling does not use the nfstables backend**”.

The simplest solution here is to reinstall the nodes on supported operating system.

Comment: Hi, you are right. I changed my OS for Centos 7. Nevertheless, I still had the issue. I found a 2nd issue is that for each VM I have two network adapters: one NAT for internet access, and one Host only Network. What happened is that Flannel took the NAT interface by default: thus I added in flannel yaml file the argument --iface=enp0s8 to make sure it uses the Host only Network interface.

Comment: Now if I check the status of my flannel pods I can see there are using the correct interface. kubectl logs kube-flannel-ds-nn6v4 -n kube-system show that interface used is enp0s8 (when before it was enp0s3). Nevertheless, even with Centos 7 and Flannel corrected configuration I still have the same issue.

Comment: What virtualization software / infrastructure are you using?

Comment: I am using VirtualBox and I deployed CentOS 8 and now 7.